# web scraping using cheerio in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, web-scraping, cheerio

I am trying web Scraping using cheerio and http in node js

part of html code:

```
<tr>
    <td id="priceblock_saleprice_lbl" class="a-color-price a-size-base a-text-right a-nowrap">Sale:</td>

    <td class="a-span12">
    <span id="priceblock_saleprice" class="a-size-medium a-color-price"><span class="currencyINR">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span> 585.00</span>

    </td>
</tr>
```

nodejs code :

```
var sale_price = '#priceblock_saleprice';
            scraper(sale_price).filter(function(){
            var data_price = scraper(this);
            console.log(data_price.text());
            scraped = scraped + data_price.text()+';';
          });

 this code is giving 585 as output.
```

but in same:

part of html page:

```
<tr id="priceblock_ourprice_row">
    <td id="priceblock_ourprice_lbl" class="a-color-secondary a-size-base a-text-right a-nowrap">Price:</td>
    <td class="a-span12">
        <span id="priceblock_ourprice" class="a-size-medium a-color-price"><span class="currencyINR">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span> 329.00</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

nodejs code:

```
var mrp  = '#priceblock_ourprice_lbl';
scraper(mrp).filter(function(){
            var data_mrp = scraper(this);
            console.log(data_mrp.text());
            scraped = scraped + data_mrp.text()+';';
          });
```

It is not giving an output.

Answer (score 0):

you are using wrong id... It should be `priceblock_ourprice`

```
var mrp  = '#priceblock_ourprice';
scraper(mrp).filter(function(){
   var data_mrp = scraper(this);
   console.log(data_mrp.text());
   scraped = scraped + data_mrp.text()+';';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The id used in the 2nd code snippet is pointing to the 1st `<td>` element , but you need to target the 2nd `<td>` element, so use 
"#priceblock_ourprice"

Comment: because in the first one the id is correct, it indicates the span which points to your price, also if replacing the id doesn't work try with the <tr> id and get its children

Comment: can you refer some tutorial where i find  how to use children and next etc

Comment: did you accomplish the task , or still need assistance ?

Comment: here is my mail sourab.reddy2k14@gmail.com , add me on hangouts